# Did Emerald City have any success stories?

Tags: oz

Emerald city in Oz was meant to be this experimental unit that gave prisoners better lives in the hopes that their rehabilitation would also go better.

But it seems like there are no actual success stories in Oz. Even the few that had minor success ultimately failed (usually by death). Were there any stories that eventually settles on a good outcome?

Answer (score 4):

Jackson Vahue, the former NBA player (played by real-life NBA player Rick Fox) was the only one I recall getting out of Oz alive and *staying* out.

I'd say in retrospect Miguel Alvarez was probably the only success story.  He really turned his life around by the time the show was over.

I'm not sure you can really call Ryan O'Reily a "success story"; every single thing that ever went wrong in his brother Cyril's life, right up to his death, was caused by Ryan.  That's a big price to pay. By the conclusion of the show, the only real positive I can point to is the reconciliation with his father.

Answer (score 3):

**It might be obvious, but massive spoilers here!**

I also asked myself this question several times, and didn't find any recurring character, except:

### [Ryan O'Reilly](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/Ryan_O%27Reily)

- Survives the 6 seasons (unexpected considering how tricky and conspiratory he his).
- Survives breast cancer.
- *I am not sure of thise one:* He might live the execution of his brother [Cyril](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/Cyril_O%27Reily) as a relief. *Personal opinion: I think the maze is his way to figure out how he should consider the death of his brother, resulting of relief and new life with Dr. Nathan).*
- Finally receives a kiss from [Dr. Nathan](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/Gloria_Nathan).
- At the end he forgives [Seamus](http://oztv.wikia.com/wiki/Seamus_O%27Reily), his father, grieving together.